# Why do MASS:lm.ridge coefficents differ from those calculated manually?

Tags: r, regression, mass

When performing ridge regression manually, as it is defined

```
solve(t(X) %*% X + lbd*I) %*%t(X) %*% y
```

I get different results from those calculated by `MASS::lm.ridge`. Why? For ordinary linear regression the manual method (computing the pseudoinverse) works fine.

Here is my Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
library(tidyverse)

ridgeRegression = function(X, y, lbd) {
  Rinv = solve(t(X) %*% X + lbd*diag(ncol(X)))
  t(Rinv %*% t(X) %*% y)
}

# generate some data:
set.seed(0)
tb1 = tibble(
  x0 = 1,
  x1 = seq(-1, 1, by=.01),
  x2 = x1 + rnorm(length(x1), 0, .1),
  y  = x1 + x2 + rnorm(length(x1), 0, .5)
)
X = as.matrix(tb1 %>% select(x0, x1, x2))

# sanity check: force ordinary linear regression
# and compare it with the built-in linear regression:
ridgeRegression(X, tb1$y, 0) - coef(summary(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=tb1)))[, 1]
# looks the same: -2.94903e-17 1.487699e-14 -2.176037e-14

# compare manual ridge regression to MASS ridge regression:
ridgeRegression(X, tb1$y, 10) - coef(MASS::lm.ridge(y ~ x0 + x1 + x2 - 1, data=tb1, lambda = 10))
# noticeably different: -0.0001407148 0.003689412 -0.08905392
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MASS::lm.ridge scales the data before modelling - this accounts for the difference in the coefficients.

You can confirm this by checking the function code by typing MASS::lm.ridge into the R console.

Here is the lm.ridge function with the scaling portion commented out:

```
X = as.matrix(tb1 %>% select(x0, x1, x2))
n <- nrow(X); p <- ncol(X)
#Xscale <- drop(rep(1/n, n) %*% X^2)^0.5
#X <- X/rep(Xscale, rep(n, p))
Xs <- svd(X)
rhs <- t(Xs$u) %*% tb1$y
d <- Xs$d
lscoef <-  Xs$v %*% (rhs/d)
lsfit <- X %*% lscoef
resid <- tb1$y - lsfit
s2 <- sum(resid^2)/(n - p)
HKB <- (p-2)*s2/sum(lscoef^2)
LW <- (p-2)*s2*n/sum(lsfit^2)
k <- 1
dx <- length(d)
div <- d^2 + rep(10, rep(dx,k))
a <- drop(d*rhs)/div
dim(a) <- c(dx, k)
coef <- Xs$v %*% a
coef
#             x0        x1        x2
#[1,] 0.01384984 0.8667353 0.9452382
```

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer. However, I'm still confused: I thought that `coef()`, when applied to the result of `lm.ridge()`, would scale the coefficients back. It obviously doesn't do that. It scales them to some other values. So what are the coefficients worth then?

Comment: I think I am somewhat confused as well. Although he coef() method does unscale the coeffcients. Ridge regression is sensitive to the scale of the original data (otherwise it would penalise variables arbitrarily based on their scale) - although your independent variables do have 0 mean they have different variances.